# + on a new line disregards parentheses. Why is that?

Tags: ruby

So today I found out this feature of ruby:

```
irb(main):001:0> (1
irb(main):002:1> + 3)
=> 3
```

If the plus comes on a new line the whole thing is not evaluated. Why is that? I would like the parentheses to be honoured in this case.

Comment: @DaveNewton: apparently, it _is_ a feature of ruby :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm wrong. Same thing happens in a script if it's an assignment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ruby interprets line break as end of expression. Your code is equivalent to

```
(1; +3)
```

which is further equivalent to

```
(1; 3)
```

And in Ruby, the last expression is the return value, which is `3`.

If you want to have a line break, then you can leave the operator in the previous line

```
(1 +
3)
# => 4
```

or use `\` to explicitly indicate a line continuation.

```
(1\
+ 3)
# => 4
```

Comment: So parentheses are disregarded sometimes when spread over several lines?

Comment: @froderik No, you don't seem to have gotten it. Parentheses are always regarded. In this case, two expressions are aligned within parentheses.

Comment: Aha - now I see. Thanks for explaining it!

Answer (score 5):

Further to @sawa's excellent answer, if you explicity call the operation as a method it'll work

```
(1.
+ 3)
=> 4
```

This is because the trailing full-stop will cause a method name on the next line to be appended.